# How To Compare Two Lists Using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string, list

I Have Two Lists,

1. `List<string>IDList //DM-0016 (ID:225),LPG Test (ID:232), 18S1(ID:290)..`
2. `List<string>Names // DM-0016,LPG Test, 18S1..`

The Second List is basically the same as the First but it doesn't have the IDs.
I am Showing the Second List in a Multiple Choice Dialog, Where, user can select multiple items.

I have a Regular Expression `(@"(?<=\(ID:)[0-9]+");` This returns only the the number inside (ID:)

I want to compare these two Lists based on this RegEX, Where, I want only the ID's of the selected items.

**For Ex:** If **DM-0061** is selected i'll get **225**.

Comment: what have you tried so far

Comment: What about splitting the strings into arrays (split on ","), then looping over the list with IDs first to map the names to IDs, then looping over the names and find the ID per name from the other array?

Comment: var match = IDList.FirstOrDefault(check => check.Contains(input)); I tried doing this, but this is applicable for only single item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a regular expression such as:

```
(?<key>.*?)\s\(ID:(?<value>[0-9]+)\)
```

This regex translates to

- A named capture group `key` consisting of:

  - Any character any number of repetitions, but as few as possible
- Whitespace
- Literal `(ID:`
- A named capture group `value` consisting of:

  - Any number, one or more repetitions
- Literal `)`

You can project your original list to a dictionary and easily use it as a lookup:

```
var list = new List<string>(){
    "DM-0016 (ID:225)","LPG Test (ID:232)", "18S1 (ID:290)"
};
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<key>.*?)\s\(ID:(?<value>[0-9]+)\)");

var dict = list.Select(i => regex.Match(i))
               .ToDictionary(
                    k => k.Groups["key"].Value, 
                    v => v.Groups["value"].Value);

Console.WriteLine(dict["DM-0016"]); // writes 225
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/PMTUFW14656

Comment: This is perfect! Could you please explain the Regex that you used?

Comment: Got it! Thanks :)