# Compare two lists and remove items that are not found in list2

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists-

```
List<String> List1;
List<File> List2;
```

The contents are as follows-

```
List1                   List2
-----                   -----
String                  ID    FileName     LastWrite

tttaaaajk34j34          1       aaa        01-02-2019
oooccc                  2       bbb        14-09-2018
ddd                     3       ccc        23-06-2019
ttt                     4       ddd        15-10-2016
aaa2832kajj             5       eee        20-08-2012
```

I want to compare List1 with List2 and remove items from List2 that are found in the List1.

**Result-**

```
List2
----
ID     FileName

2       bbb
4       ddd
5       eee
```

**My Code-**

```
List1.Where(f => !List1.Any(str => str.FileName.Contains(List2)))
```

**The Problem-**

This doesn't work. It throws below exception as List2 is a List, unlike List1 which is List.

```
'String does not contain a definition for filename and no extension method filename accepting a first argument of type string..
```

Comment: I suggest you re-read the question and [edit] it to clarify what it is you actually want.

Comment: You must use a regular expression on the filename: [Regex Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8). Here is an example as duplicated answer: [how-to-compare-two-lists-using-regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555021/how-to-compare-two-lists-using-regex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just filter out the files using LINQ:

```
List1.Where(f => !List2.Any(str => str.Contains(f.FileName)))
```

Explanation:

- Use [`Enumerable.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) to first filter out the files from `List1`, you want to keep.
- Use [`String.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8) to check if [`Enumerable.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) of the files from `List2` have substring filenames `FileName` from `List1`. In this case we make sure to use `!` operator in the predicate to ensure we don't keep files that have been found in `List2`.

**UPDATE**

As per updated requirements in the question just switch around `List1` and `List2`. Your new query should be:

```
List2.Where(f => !List1.Any(str => str.Contains(f.FileName)))
```

Comment: apologizes. I just realized I made a blunder while writing my question. The list which contains ID, File Name, Last Write Time is actually not List1. It's List 2. And the list that contains strings is List1. Can you help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ILoveIndia I believe with the query I have given you can modify it to your new requirements. It would simply be a matter of just switching things around. Furthermore, your current update still does not reflect the changes in your comment above.

Comment: I receive this error: Cannot convert from system.collections.generic.list<string> to string when I run the modified query:             List1.Where(f => !List1.Any(str => str.FileName.Contains(List2)));

Comment: Thanks for the reply RoadRunner. But it throws exception 'String does not contain a definition for filename..." as List2 is a List<String>, unlike List1 which is List<t>

Comment: @ILoveIndia Please update your question, your requirements are ambiguous and unclear right now. I'm getting confused...